# Magento 2.1 Tax Set Up

Tags: magento-2.1, tax, rules

I would like to make tax rules in my store:

1. All foreign customers: 0% Tax
2. All Dutch customers:

   a) up to 10000 Euro: 21% Tax

   b) from 10000 Euro: 0% Tax

How should i do this and is it even possible in Magento 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set up such tax rate in ***Tax Rates*** section.

One hacky workaround I can suggest to you:

1. Set up Tax Rate (Stores -> Taxes -> Tax zones and Rates) with following settings:

   - Zip/Post Code: *
   - Country: Netherlands
   - Rate Percent: 21
2. Set up Cart Rule (Marketing -> Promotions -> Cart Price Rules) with following settings:

   - Websites: select website where you want it applied
   - Customer Groups: select customer groups (you probably want to select all)
   - In ***Conditions*** tab, add condition: ***Subtotal*** greater than 10000
   - In ***Conditions*** tab, add one more condition: ***Shipping country*** is Netherland
   - In ***Actions*** tab, put ***Discount Amount***: 21 (and ***Apply to shipping amount***)